# Deep and shallow merge in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, copy

What is the difference between deep and shallow merge of objects in javascript?
As far as I understand, deep merge recursively copies all the source object enumerable properties into target object. But what does shallow merge do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: @FirstOrGoat: Copying and merging are two different things.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In a shallow merge, the properties of the first object are overwritten with the same property values of the second object.

Lets look at an example. Setup:

```
var obj1 = {
  foo: {
    prop1: 42,
  },
};

var obj2 = {
  foo: {
    prop2: 21,
  },
  bar: {
    prop3: 10,
  },
};
```

Shallow:

```
var result = {
  foo: {          // `foo` got overwritten with the value of `obj2`
    prop2: 21,
  },
  bar: {
    prop3: 10,
  },
};
```

Deep:

```
var result = {
  foo: {
    prop1: 42,
    prop2: 21,    // `obj2.foo` got merged into `obj1.foo`.
  },
  bar: {
    prop3: 10,
  },
};
```

Comment: Is it that shallow merge just checks the first level properties in the object to merge? say for example , we have var obj1 = {
  foo: {
    prop1: 42,
    foosInnerObj: {
    someProp: someVal    
}
  },
};
Does shallow merge ignore 'foosInnerObj' completely? and keeps only prop2 from obj2 in foo?

Comment: Yep. It's basically just `obj1.foo = obj2.foo;` (assuming you merge into `obj1`). Hence the term "shallow".

Comment: Thanks felix, It helped :)