# Why doesn't merging a prototype to another object via Object.assign() work?

Tags: javascript

So I have this `class` definition:

```js
class Field {
    constructor(canvas) {
        const CANVAS = document.querySelector(canvas);
        const CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext("2d");

        return Object.assign(CONTEXT, Field.prototype); // *
    }

    prototypeMethodName() {
        return "something";
    }
}

console.log(new Field("canvas"));
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The main idea here is that when I invoke `new Field()` I get not the instance of `Field`, but the object consisting of two other objects: `CONTEXT` and `Field.prototype`. The `CONTEXT` is the instance of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, and, basically, I just want to augument it with other methods (in this example it's just one method `prototypeMethodName()`).

But in this case I get a bare `CONTEXT` object that doesn't contain any of "my" properties.

I also noticed that the `assign` method doesn't work correctly only when I'm trying to merge a prototype of something to the tatget object. So the thing here is not about the `CONTEXT` object, but is about the prototype.

Why doesn't my code work? What would I do to make it work then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731453/deep-and-shallow-merge-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to augument it with other methods

[Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572). Use composition instead.

> But I get a bare CONTEXT object that doesn't contain any of "my" properties.
>   I also noticed that the assign method doesn't work correctly only when I'm trying to merge a prototype of something to the target object.

Yes. The prototype objects of `class`es are not containing any [*enumerable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) methods, so `Object.assign` doesn't find them. Have a look at [ES6 Iterate over class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30881632/1048572).

Comment: Allright. I got the part about enumerables. But I think you are wrong about extending native objects. The thing is I don't extend it globaly (on a global level). Instead, I just want a separate copy that is augumented with my own methods. I just wanna say that, I think, it would be bad of me if I would extend the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`'s prototype globaly, but I don't do that.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for pointing me to enumerables. I'll try to find another way to satisfy my needle.

Comment: @smellyshovel yes, extending local instances might be OK (if you control where these instances are used and where not) and is certainly better than extending a native prototype object, but you still risk name collisions with future extensions of the web platform.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
merge(context, field) {
    for(let prop in Field.prototype) {
        context.prototype[prop] = Field.prototype[prop];
    }
    return context;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it might work cause if I remember correctly `for in` only loops throgh enumerable props. And, how Bergi said, the properties of prototypes are not enumerable.